# The integral kernel of $(\Delta)^{-1}$ is $1/|x-y|$

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, book-recommendation, laplacian

I am following Barry Simon on the semigroup $e^{tH}$, for $t$ a real number.  The paper is called “Schrödinger semigroups”. In it he says casually that ’the function $| x — y |^{-1}$ arises in the definition of [some function space] because it is (up to a
constant) the integral kernel of $(\Delta)^{-1}$.’

It sounds like this is related to the Riesz–Fréchet representation. Is that correct? Can I calculate these kernels in some way such that I can see what the integral kernel might be for some common operations, for example the inverse of the laplacian? Please recommend literature if possible.

Comment: This is the fundamental solution/Green's function for the Laplacian, which can be interpreted as the inverse of the operator since $$\Delta u = f \implies u = \int f\cdot G$$ where $$\Delta G = \delta_0$$

Comment: Of course, but how can I calculate these integral kernels

Comment: You can take the Fourier transform of that second line of equations that I wrote and solve, or you can show that $\Delta \frac{1}{|x|} = \delta_0$ in the sense of distributions by using divergence theorem (or integration by parts as its called)